# IDL - Reshape 2D-Array to 3D-Array

Tags: image, video, rgb, grayscale, idl

In IDL I have an datacube containing (grayscale) images at different times: datacube[w, h, frames]. Now I want to convert that datacube into an animation using IDLFFVideoWrite, but the problem is, the Put-Method only eats frames of the sort frame[3, w, h].

How can I convert a single frame of my datacube into a fitting frame, that IDLffVideoWrite::Put will eat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have greyscale images, so we need to make all three bands (R, G, and B) just copies of the one band. `REBIN` and `REFORM` are the tools for "juggling dimensions" like that:

```
frame = rebin(reform(datacube[*, *, i], 1, w, h), 3, w, h)
```

As long as `datacube` is of byte data, `frame` will be suitable for `IDLffVideoWrite::put`.

UPDATE: editing answer because I have limited formatting options in a comment.

So you actually have a `datacube` of this form then:

```
datacube[w, h, 3 * n_frames]
```

So you should do this to `datacube` to make it easier to deal with:

```
datacube = transpose(reform(datacube, w, h, 3, n_frames), [2, 0, 1, 3])
```

Then, to get the `i`th frame, you can just do:

```
frame = reform(datacube[*, *, *, i])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just an other small question, I have reformatted my datacube to play around with my data, now the cube contains RGB-Data, but is still of the form datacube[w, h, frames], for example frame 0 contains Red, frame 1 contains Green and frame 2 contains Blue, and then again frame 3 contains Red etc.

How would I format this now efficiently in a correct frame for the Put-Method?